# Stored procedure Firebird for merging duplicates

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Let's say in a table we have multiple row insertions every 10 seconds like this:

```
ID     ts         col1    col2    col3   
1      00:00:00   1234    3456    4567
2      00:00:10   1234    3456    4567
3      00:00:20   1234    3456    4567
4      00:00:30   1234    3456    4567
5      00:00:40   1234    3456    4567
6      00:00:50   1234    3456    4567
```

Like described, everything besides the ID and TS columns is equal. The duplicates are not needed, just an updated version of them. I'm thinking of making a stored procedure and trigger to automate the row merging and want to have a result like this:

```
ID     ts         col1      col2    col3   
1      00:00:00   1234x5    3456    4567   
6      00:00:50   1234      3456    4567
```

As you can imagine such a database expands fast. So the idea is to slow down the expansion by merging the duplicate records into one row every 5 times the record shows.

Until now I managed to get all the duplicates with:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, col1, col2, col3 
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY col1, col2, col3 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 AND a.col3 = b.col3;
```

After this it came to mind `ROW_COUNT` - if I can use the number of records produced by the upper statement in a procedure and after that to make the merge based on it. But unfortunately my knowledge ends here.

So my question is - is it even possible to make such thing? If yes then how?

Comment: And what will happen if the consolidation produces multiple rows of the form `col1 = 1234x5 col2=3456 col3 = 4567`? Would they need to be consolidated to `col1 = 1234x5x5`, etc? Is there a maximum spread of `ts` values? What logic should be applied to derive the `ts` value?

Comment: Didn't think that `col1 = 1234x5x5` was an option lol. Now when I think about it, it will happen and the result will be 1 row with `1234x5x5x ..xn`. But no this wouldn't be a desired result. Some logic would be - if from `00:00:00 to 00:00:50` `col1` is `1234` `update col1 = 1234x5` or something like that. I hope I'm explainig this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of INSERT for these rows you should use UPDATE OR INSERT (or MERGE) statement like this

```
MERGE INTO t
 USING (SELECT 1 ID, _time'00:00:00' ts, 1234 col1, 3456 col2, 4567 col3 FROM rdb$database) AS d
 ON t.ID = d.ID and t.col1 = d.col1 and t.col3 = d.col3
 WHEN MATCHED UPDATE SET t.end_ts = d.ts, t.r_count = t.r_count + 1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT (ID, ts, end_ts, r_count, col1, col2, col3) VALUES (d.ID, d.ts, d.ts, 1, d.col1, d.col2, d.col3)
```

Comment: I like this solution, unfortunately I don't have control on how the records are being added.

Comment: If you have control over the database just replace the table with a view and you'll get it.

Comment: So I have to create a view that has the duplicates in it, with for example the command I provided in the question, and then to use this merge statement with that view, correct?

Comment: No, you create a view to gain control on INSERTs and replace them with whatever you want in the view's triggers. Read about "updatable views".